# If R is uncountable, then (0.1) is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I am trying to prove that (0.1) is uncountable given that R is uncountable.

I start by assuming that (0.1) is countable.

Then there exists a bijective map between (0.1) and N.

I guess then we can construct bijective map for (1.2) also.

this shows that each (i-1,i) for i=intergers is countable.

then Union of (i-1,i) is countable, which does not make sense since R is uncountable?

any suggestion please

Comment: The idea is good. Another hint, if you know some trigonometry: you can consider $f(x)=\tan\left(\pi x-\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ defined over the interval $(0,1)$, which is…

Comment: I did not realized that we could also use trigonometric function..

Comment: You can also use $f(x)=\dfrac{2x-1}{x(1-x)}$ (again defined over $(0,1)$).

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track. To make your idea a bit more rigorous, say there exists a bijection $f: (0,1) \to \mathbb{N}$. Show that, for each integer $k$, $f_k:(k,k+1)\to \mathbb{N}$ given by $f_k(x)=f(x)+k$ is a bijection. Hence $(k,k+1)$ is countable for each $k$.

Now, note that: $$\Bbb{R}=\Bbb{Z}\cup \bigcup_{k\in \Bbb{Z}}(k,k+1)$$

The countable union of countable sets is...

Comment: Countable! Thanks a lot

Comment: @user268336 My pleasure. If you found my answer helpful, feel free to accept it so others can see that the issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Here is alternate method:

Define $f:(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}\;$ by $\;\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{2x-1}{x(1-x)}$.

Then $f$ is injective since $\displaystyle f^{\prime}(x)=\frac{2x^2-2x+1}{x^2(1-x)^2}>0$ for $x\in(0,1)$,

and $f$ is surjective since $f$ is continuous with $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0^{+}}f(x)=-\infty$ and $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to1^{-}}f(x)=\infty$.

Therefore $f$ is a bijection between $(0,1)$ and $\mathbb{R}$.